# A question about the room of requirement

Tags: harry-potter, magical-theory

The room of requirement is supposed to fulfill the seeker's needs. Voldemort **needed** to hide his Hocrux where **none** could reach. Now how come Harry Potter could find the Hocrux hidden in the room of requirement?. Is the magic of the room limited to time?

Suppose someone says I need a place to hide where none could reach before hiding. If another person enters the room and after saying I need that particular thing to be found. What would happen then ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the question - Tom Riddle believed he was the only one who knew of the room so he didnt need to ask "Show me a room that no one else can enter". Remember that he was arrogant enough to believe that he plumbed depths no other person could plumb.

In DH Neville states that if he asks the room to stop the Carrows then it will, but you have to specifically ask for the things you need.

In short Voldy was too arrogant to believe that anyone else could even find the room to request extra defences.

Comment: @ Steven Wood Suppose someone did say **I need a place to hide where none could reach** before hiding. If another person enters the room and after saying **I need that particular thing to be found**. What would happen then

Comment: I am not sure but I imagine that a temporal paradox would ensue and Amelia Earhart would appear :-) There are a lot of things like that that are unexplained.

Comment: If the request was that a hiding place that no one else can find is the request, than that is what is granted, and no one else can enter the room, as evidenced in Deathly Hallows.  As Steven mentioned, if you are specific enough, it will provide.  JKR never mentioned the room failing, so we must assume it can do anything that is magically possible.

Comment: @ Dave Johnson Let the other person's request be **to find that particular hidden thing** what then? Surely the Room would fail in one case.